# Django: Checking content type of response in tests

Tags: django, testing, content-type

I have Django view that returns a HTTPResponse with content type 'application/json'. In my tests, I want to verify the expected content type was set.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects), I see that a HTTPResponse I can pass the content_type has a parameter, put not get it as an attribute. Why is that?

In my `views.py`, I build and send out a HTTPResponse like this:

```
j = json.dumps(j)
return HttpResponse(j, content_type='application/json')
```

In my `tests.py`, I would like to do something like

```
self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'application/json')
```

But without the attribute on the HTTPResponse object, that of course fails with `AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'content_type'`

*How can I get the content type of the response in Django? Am misunderstanding something about the workings of HTTP?*

Comment: run `print(dir(response))` and see there is a `content_type` attribute or not

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I didn't know about that possibility, and seeing all the attributes helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be `response['content-type']` which would return `'application/json'` in your case.  So to test you would use:

`self.assertEqual(response['content-type'], 'application/json')`

Answer (score 3):

The [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__getitem__) for the Django `HttpResponse` mentions:

> `HttpResponse.__getitem__(header)`
>   Returns the value for the given header name. Case-insensitive.

This MDN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) mentions that in a HTTP response the Content Type is a header with name `Content-Type`.

So the following code returns the Content Type of a Django `HttpResponse`:

```py
response.__getitem__('Content-Type')
```

This could be used in a Django test to assert that the Content Type has a certain value, for example to assert that the Content Type of the `HttpResponse` is `application/json`:

```py
self.assertEqual(response.__getitem__('content-type'), 'application/json')
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your code does exactly? This way other people stumbling across this question have a chance to solve a similar problem theirselfes.

Comment: `response['content-type']` seems be the same as `response.__getitem__('content-type')` "under te hood". Using the first executes the second.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, a HTTPResponse object in Django has an `_content_type_for_repr` attribute.
Here's what it contained (for me):

```
print(response._content_type_for_repr)
, "application/json"
```

I have no clue why it's in this format, but slicing it got me where I wanted:
`self.assertEqual(response._content_type_for_repr[3:-1], 'application/json')`

(If anybody has a more elegant solution to this, don't hesitate it to post it!)